# check specfic words in the records using cucumber, capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

In my code they have one table. In that table the row is not fixed. it may added by everyone.

[image]

I that table every third column text should be "Pending". It is the condition. I dont know How to check that every third column text have "Pending".

I was trying this. I dont know weather its right or not.

```
page.should have_selector('tbody tr td:nth-child(3)', text: Pending)
```

Its my html

```
<table id="thisis" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Default</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="2">Test1</a></td>
            <td>true</td>
            <td>
                <span class="label label-success">Pending</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span><a href="2">View</a></span>
                <span>/</span>
                <span><a href="2/edit">Edit</a></span>
                <span>/</span>
                <span><a href="2/publish">Publish</a></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="4">test2</a></td>
            <td>true</td>
            <td>
                <span class="label label-success">Pending</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span><a href="4">View</a></span>
                <span>/</span>
                <span><a href="4/edit">Edit</a></span>
                <span>/</span>
                <span><a href="4/publish">Publish</a></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for your valuable answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Method 1: Use count

Say you have 10 rows in a page, and given your status columns have class "status". Then

```
expect(page).to have_css(".status", text: "Pending", count: 10)
```

### Method 2: Use scope

To code a table with data, a convention is to assign unique id to each row at least. This will help lots of functions not only the test.

What you need to do is:

1. Assign an unique CSS id with data id for each row
2. Add a "status" class for status column for easy identifying

You view will look like this

```
<tr id="123-row">
  <td>bla blah</td>
  <td><span class="label label-success status">Pending</span>
  ...
</tr>
```

Then, for test, you can do this in Capybara:

```
within "##{item.id}-row .status"
  expect(page).to have_content("Pending")
end
```

Comment: can you please tell me `within` function. here "#{item.id}-row .status" for class identifier?

Comment: @Selva, `within` is Capybara's method to limit scope to a certain DOM element. You can check their doc for details. The selection rule is same as CSS.

Comment: One more hash needed and added.

Comment: may i use this code `within "#subscription-list-controls table.table tbody tr td:nth-child(3) span"
  expect(page).to have_content("Pending")
end` May i know will it take all the 3rd `td` span?

Comment: @Selva, yes you can, but it's better to be as simple as possible otherwise you lose the flexibility to revise template.

Comment: but i'm getting an error message. `Unable to find css "#thisis .label"`. I updated my html here. My cucumber is `Then /^I should see the pending$/ do
  within("#thisis .label") do
    expect(page).to have_content("Pending") 
  end
end`

Comment: You can try to find it manually in browser console. Also why the CSS id doesn't have unique item id? You'll end with multiple duplicate css ids.